# Does individual almost sure implies joint almost sure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

We know that $\liminf X_n\geq1$ and $\limsup X_n\leq1$ implies $\lim X_n=1 $for real sequence.

But does $P(\liminf X_n\geq1)=1$ and $P(\limsup X_n\leq1)=1$ implies $P(\lim X_n=1)=1$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. More generally, if $P(A) = 1$ and $P(B) = 1$, then $P(A \cup B) = 1$ since $1=P(A) \leq P(A \cup B) \leq 1$, and so $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = 1 + 1 - 1 = 1$.